# MessageBox.Show not working in a modal child form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to use messagebox in winforms C#. I have a child form that I am using as a modal form. My child form is as follows :

```
popup newpopup = new popup(prt.myIP);
newpopup.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
newpopup.Location =   new Point(Loc.X + 30, 60 );
popup.ShowDialog();
```

MessageBox.show works fine in the parent form, but code hangs when I try to use it in my child form (in popup.cs).

```
MessageBox.Show("Text", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

Comment: Please post more code showing more context.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `IWin32Window owner` parameter?

Comment: Been a while since I did winforms, but i think you would use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba2a6d06(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass `this` as the first parameter

Comment: @stuartd I tried passing "this" as parameter in the MessageBox, but still no luck. Surprisingly the messagebox appears if I press ALT or use ALT+TAB

Comment: what happens if you don't set the StartPosition and Location?

Comment: @nozzleman still no change.

Comment: `code hangs when I try to use it in my child form`  You probably have to document your child form better.

Comment: `but code hangs when I try to use it in my child form (in popup.cs)` <-- start commenting out other code in your child and/or parent form, see at which point it starts to work. You may have implemented common "bad practices" in your WinForms app, which make you app very fragile, as you make further changes to it.

Comment: Try passing the owner parameter to both the child form (from the main one) and then to the message box (from the child form). It's clear that the message displays, but it appears covered by other windows, giving the impression of a hang application.

Comment: @Neolisk The code only hangs when I call MessageBox.Show(). Remaining works properly.

Answer (score 3):

I just tested it with a form that opens a child form eg.

```
popup newpopup = new popup(); 
newpopup.ShowDialog();
```

Messagebox.show worked fine, what I did see in your question were these 2 lines:

```
popup newpopup = new popup(prt.myIP);
popup.ShowDialog();
```

As you might be able to see, you are trying to call the form itself instead of the instance you just made. If this is in your normal code change it to:

```
popup newpopup = new popup(prt.myIP);
newpopup.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I corrected that mistake, but still no change.

Comment: If it still won't work it means the problem isn't in the code you provided. If you use my version of the popup (top example) it should work (Mine doesn't pass prt.myIP)